# How to make the input and output color different in Terminal?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal, pycharm, textcolor

In Pycharm-run, the input text color is always green and Italic while the output is always in plain text in white, which really helps me to distinguish the input from the output. How do I do that in Linux terminal or in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux mint and i can easily change the color of font , color of palette, output color, size and all by opening the terminal -> Edit -> Preferences. It has all the options .I hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't that change the input color too?

Comment: you can change and specify each and every thing.!

Answer (score 0):

1. open the bash terminal
2. go to .bashrc using vi or nano
3. at the end of the file add the PS1

- PS1="\e[1;31m\u@\h \W$ \e[0;0m"
- This code at the end of the rc file will make your prompt red and bold

There are many ways you can change by manipulating the characters in it.
Here is an useful link: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/change-bash-prompt-linux